# Send base64 image from meteor application

Tags: javascript, php, meteor, base64

I have a meteor application and in this one I use [cropper plugin](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper) to upload an image from the local computer of the user in the website and after send it to my DigitalOcean server. So the upload from the local computer works but when I try to send the image in my server, it doesn't work.

From cropper plugin, I retrieve a imgbase64 I want to send.

I search on many forums but I didn't find a good solution so I tried to do this :

In `myapp.js` I have :

```
    $("#save").click(function() {
    window.open($image.cropper("getDataURL"));
    var dataURL = $image.cropper("getDataURL");
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "script.php",
          data: { 
             imgBase64: dataURL
          }
        }).done(function(o) {
          console.log('saved'); 
          // If you want the file to be visible in the browser 
          // - please modify the callback in javascript. All you
          // need is to return the url to the file, you just saved 
          // and than put the image in your browser.
        });
});
```

In `myapp.html` I have

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" id="save" type="submit">Save</button>
```

And I have a php script :

```
<?php
    // requires php5
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/images/');
    $img = $_POST['img'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
    //header('Location: '.$_POST['return_url']);

?>
```

When I click on save button, I get "saved" in the console but I have nothing in the folder.
Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Are you trying to use PHP within a Meteor application?

Comment: Yes, because I don't know how to do it differently. I tried to use cfs:filesystem but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it looks like you aren't using Meteor correctly.

Meteor is a JavaScript framework, so you can't create PHP files and try to initiate them within Meteor. All of your code has to be JavaScript.

This is a fundamental part of meteor development. [I suggest you try the Meteor tutorial which should help you learn how to use Meteor.](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app)

The code you have posted will not achieve what you want to achieve, you will need to remove the PHP and rewrite it in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. So, do you know how to do it in javascript ?